# Return multiple classes java

Tags: java

So I'm trying to write an API for an game and i made 4 different classes named ShipScanStage0, ShipScanStage1, ShipScanStage2, ShipScanStage3 which I want to return in this class.

I tried to set the return type of getScanStageInfo to Object but that is not the kinda of solution im looking for I want a clean and simply way for API users to gain access to the scanStage and use the Information of it.

```java
ShipTargetedEvent.java

    package org.xenodev.edj.events;

    import org.xenodev.edj.Event;
    import org.xenodev.edj.events.storage.ShipScanStage0;

    public class ShipTargetedEvent extends Event {

    int scanStage;

    public ShipTargetedEvent(String timestamp, int scanStage) {
        super(timestamp);
        this.scanStage = scanStage;
    }

    public void getScanStageInfo() {
        if(scanStage == 0) {
            return new ShipScanStage0();
        }else if(scanStage == 1) {
            return new ShipScanStage1();
        }else if(scanStage == 2) {
            return new ShipScanStage2();
        }else if(scanStage == 3) {
            return new ShipScanStage3();
        }
     }

    }
```

I want to achieve that users can access only information from the StageScan level because if the scanStage level is 2 and they access the scanStage level 3 class they are gonna have some uninitialized variables cause the game didnt provide that information.

Comment: That's exactly where you use interface.

Comment: The subject of the question should not be "return multiple classes". That immediately made me think you want to return a composite class of objects when you are asking about returning an abstract class or an interface.

Comment: I'm sorry I didnt know what I should call it and since im returning the instances of classes i thought it would fit this question well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're saying that each `ShipScanStage`-type object is similar, then it would have similar-enough functionality.

If this is the case, then each one of those objects should either extend from an abstract class or implement an interface.

...Then, you actually have to return either that abstract type or interface from your method.

Supposing that the abstract class or interface was named `ShipScanStage`, then the signature of your method would be:

```
public ShipScanStage getScanStageInfo() {

}
```

Comment: ah okay i understand but my problem is that ShipScanStage3 extends from ShipScanStage2, ShipScanStage2 extends from ShipScanStage 1 and ShipScanStage1 from ShipScanStage0 since the old values stay only new ones get added per stage.

Comment: That seems...odd.  Using inheritance to hold information like that seems a bit strange, but no matter; if you implement the methods specific to the class which it needs, then you can either extend an abstract class or implement an interface anyway.

Comment: ah right gotcha! I'm sorry im still studying java I really should finish it before I start something like that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve this, one common way is to use a [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to abstract the implementation and return the root interface. In implementation it would look like:

Define a common interface

```
public interface ScanStageInfo() {

}
```

Have different implementations of this based off the stage:

```
public class ScanStageOneInfo implements ScanStageInfo {

}

public class ScanStageTwoInfo implements ScanStageInfo {

}

public class ScanStageThreeInfo implements ScanStageInfo {

}

public class ScanStageFourInfo implements ScanStageInfo {

}
```

Return based of the business logic

```
    public ScanStageInfo getScanStageInfo() {
        if (scanStage == 0) {
            return new ScanStageOneInfo();
        } else if(scanStage == 1) {
            return new ScanStageTwoInfo();
        } else if(scanStage == 2) {
            return new ScanStageThreeInfo();
        } else if(scanStage == 3) {
            return new ScanStageFourInfo();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Remove the () from the class definition. ie. public class ScanStageOneInfo without ()